# Solve Double Integral with Polar System

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\iint\limits_{\Omega}{(x+y)dx dy}$ where the area $\Omega$ is bounded by a curve $x^2+y^2=x+y$. Note: Evaluate by converting to polar system.

My Solve: $$\iint\limits_{\Omega}{(x+y)dx dy}=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}} r \,(r\sin\theta + r\cos\theta)dr=$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)d\theta*\left.{\frac{r^3}{3}}\right\rvert_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}=?$$

My Question: The answer in the book is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I don't understand how they got it. Maybe when I switched to the polar coordinates I did something wrong? Sorry for asking help for simple question.

Comment: Why do you think $0\le r\le\frac1{\sqrt2}$?

Comment: @user170231 i built a graph and found the radius of the circle, we were taught this at a seminar

Comment: Before evaluating the integral and before finding the limits you need to identify the region.

Comment: @MadhanKumar Wouldn't that just be finding the area of the circle? In other examples, I was able to solve approximately similar tasks. We just found the angle (Theta) and the radius.

Comment: When you do not have any integrand function you can do that as it is just the area of two similar circles. But will  not work if it has an integrand.

Comment: In typical polar coordinates, the equation of the curve is [*not*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=convert+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3Dx%2By+to+polar+coordinates) $r=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. If you want to use this equation - which is a good idea! - try moving the origin first by choosing suitable constants $a,b$, so you instead substitute $(x,y)\to(r\cos\theta-a,r\sin\theta-b)$.

Comment: I think you did not account for shifting the coordinate system to the center of the circle before rewriting to polar coordinates

Comment: @3dguy as I understand it, is it important to take into account the displacement of the circle from the center of coordinates? I just don't really understand how this can affect calculations.

Comment: yes, basically you are asked to calculate the volume of a truncated cylinder. The integrand is the height at a point in the circle. originally, it is zero for (0,0) and 2 for (1,1) After converting to polar coordinates, not taking into account the extra r, the integrand should then also reach 2 for pi/4 and zero for 5*pi/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area is bounded by a circle around $(1/2,1/2)$ with radius $1/\sqrt{2}\,:$
$$
0=x^2-x+y^2-y=(x-\tfrac12)^2+(y-\tfrac12)^2-\tfrac12\,.
$$
Expressing the integral in $(r,\theta)$ has to take into account where
the center of the circle is:

> $$\iint\limits_\Omega(x+y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\Big\{(r\cos\theta+\tfrac12)+(r\sin\theta+\tfrac12)\Big\}r\,d\theta\,dr=\frac\pi 2\,.$$

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but when you substituted the values in (x + y)dxdy, why didn't another r appear in the integral? like ((rcosθ + 1/2) + (rsinθ + 1/2))rdθdr

Comment: @reiwoo This is not a silly question at all. I made a silly mistake!

Comment: Fun fact, the volume of an oblique cylinder is the base times the height reached along the axis, because that will be the average height. Or, in analytical terms, you can drop the terms in cos and sin in the integrand, because they will be zero when integrated over [o, 2pi]